# Magit with-editor issue

Tags: git, emacs, magit

I have installed magit-2.11.0  and I can run magit-status fine.  However when I do magit-commit  I run into this error:

> "Symbol’s function definition is void: magit-run-git-with-editor"

I see that this function is being called at various places but not defined anywhere.  How do I solve this issue? Is there any other setup that I require? I am running Emacs 25.1.1 and Cygwin git 2.11.0.  I conclude that it may have to do with dependency with-editor but I cannot figure it out.   Thanks.

update:Solved.

Comment: How did you install magit? Using `package-list-packages` etc. should install all the dependencies.

Comment: I have used M-x package-list-packages and it has installed with-editor dependency as well.